# Use chef-solo to install Oracle JDK 7

Tags: java, chef

Assume I have the java cookbook and its dependencies downloaded from http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks and can run chef-solo successfully.

Is there a command that I can run to install the latest Oracle JDK onto a Linux box, that does not involve creating a new recipe or editing the attributes/default.rb file in cookbook/java?

I know that I can use the -o option to provide the runlist...

I guess that I would need to use -j some-file-with.json to override the attributes... but I haven't been able to figure out what that json content looks like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`chef-solo` is looking for a json file (when specified) with [this format](http://docs.opscode.com/chef_solo.html#attributes).

So to run your specific scenario, you'd want something like this:

```
{
  "java": {
    "install_flavor": "oracle_rpm",
    "jdk_version": "7",
    "oracle": {
      "accept_oracle_download_terms": true
    }
  },
  "run_list": [
    "recipe[java]"
  ]
}
```

Best of luck!